# importxml в гугл таблицах. Сохранение изменений данных

Tags: google-spreadsheet, формулы

Есть ячейка, где  формулой importxml  беру данные с сайта. На сайте эти данные периодически обновляются.
Как периодически обновлять данные и сохранить обновленные значения?

Answer (score 1):

Подробно весь процесс описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872967/periodically-refresh-importxml-spreadsheet-function). По сути дела, Вам необходимы:

- скрипт, временно удаляющий формулу с IMPORTXML из ячейки, а затем - восстанавливающий её там же
- временной триггер, запускающий этот скрипт с нужной Вам периодичностью

В каких-то случаях вместо триггера по времени лучше сделать запуск скрипта вручную или при открытии таблиц, то есть использовать обновление данных лишь тогда, когда это действительно актуально.